# make .url (internet shortcut) files go to the url

Tags: iis

Is there a way to have .url files direct to the url the file is shortcutting?
I am listing files in a directory on my webpge and a couple of them are .url files. I'd like for the user to click on those files to go to the url that it is a shortcut of. However, the files currently just get downloaded. Can I get IIS to handle these files properly?